# Problem about Expected Value

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

$B=\{b(s): 0\leq s \leq 1 \}$ (Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

$ \displaystyle r\left(\theta \right)=\underset{0\le s\le 1}{\mathrm{sup}}({b}_{s}.{e}_{\theta})-\underset{0\le s\le 1}{\mathrm{inf}}({b}_{s}.
{e}_{\theta})$ where $ {e}_{\theta}=(\mathrm{cos}\theta ,\mathrm{sin}\theta ) $

For any $a,h>0$,
 $ \mathbb{E}\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert \ge 2h(\mathbb{P}(X\le a )).\mathbb{P}(X\ge a+h) $, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent copies of $X:=r(0)$.

Proof. We have

$ \mathbb{E}\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert\ge \mathbb{E}\left[\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert 1\left\{X_1\le a,X_2\ge a+h\right\}\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert 1\left\{X_2\le a,X_1\ge a+h\right\}\right]$     $ \mathbb{E}\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert\ge h(\mathbb{P}(X_1\le a )).\mathbb{P}(X_2\ge a+h) +h(\mathbb{P}(X_2\le a )).\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge a+h) ?$

I would like to know how you get the last inequality (Thanks for your support).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's $r(x)$? Also you have not stated the condition of $\mathbb{P}(X \geq a + h)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the reversed triangular inequality: if $   x_1 \leqslant a$ and $   x_2 \geqslant a+h$, then 
$$
\left\lvert x_1-x_2\right\vert\geqslant \left\lvert \left\lvert x_1 \right\vert  -\left\lvert  x_2\right\vert \right\vert \geqslant \left\lvert  x_2\right\vert-\left\lvert  x_1\right\vert\geqslant a+h-a=h
$$
Therefore, the following inequality holds almost surely;
$$
\left\lvert  X_1-X_2\right\vert\mathbf 1\left\{  X_1 \leqslant a,  X_2 \gt a+h\right\}\geqslant h\cdot \mathbf 1\left\{  X_1 \leqslant a, X_2 \gt a+h\right\}.
$$
Then integrate.